# A typo in a patent claims

Tags: us6415316

Claim 3 in US patent 6,415,316 reads

> 3. The method of claim 1 wherein the diary page is organized according to **at east** one of: by date and by topic.

What is the legal consequence of having such a typo — can this particular claim be enforced?

Comment: General questions about patent law belong at Ask Patents Meta: http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clear-cut enough typo can be fixed by a [certificate of correction](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1481.html) from the USPTO.

A obvious error with no question as to what was meant can be corrected by a court in the course of an infringement case. This quote is from case where the Federal Circuit allowed "and" to be added between the two words "detect analyze" in [a case](http://www.cafc.uscourts.gov/images/stories/opinions-orders/10-1202-1203.pdf) in 2011. But it took an appeal to get this correct (in my opinion) result.

> It is well-settled law that, in a patent infringement suit, a district court may correct an obvious error in a patent claim. I.T.S. Rubber Co. v. Essex Rubber Co., 272 U.S. 429, 442 (1926) (“Essex”). In Novo Industries, we held that “[a] district court can correct a patent only if (1) the correction is not subject to reasonable debate based on consideration of the claim language and the specification and (2) the prosecution history does not suggest a differ- ent interpretation of the claims.” 350 F.3d at 1357. We concluded that the enactment of 35 U.S.C. §§ 254 and 255 did not overrule Essex or deny authority to the district courts to correct a claim in appropriate circumstances. Id. at 1356. In Novo Industries, we declined to make the proposed corrections to the claim at issue because those corrections were substantively significant and required guesswork as to what was intended by the patentee in order to make sense of the patent claim. Id. at 1357.

It is also fixable by a [reissue proceeding at the USPTO.](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1401.html)